# No Terminal Pane in Android Studio 1.5.1

Tags: android, android-studio

I recently updated the Android Studio to 1.5.1, and I am not able to find Terminal Pane any where. I Searched in Views, I searched in Search panel, but it is no where to be found. Any idea?

Comment: Try `Tools -> Open Terminal` ?

Comment: Yep I had tried that. But didn't work because it was disabled in plugins. After enabling in plugin it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Terminal was disabled in plugins, I went to settings->plugins and checked Terminal and restarted studio, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

View -> Tool Windows -> Terminal

You can also just press ALT+F12

Hope it help